# How do I configure which DNS server docker uses in Docker Desktop for Mac?

Tags: docker, dns, docker-for-mac, docker-desktop

The built in DNS server in **Docker Desktop for Mac** is really slow, so I'd like to use a different DNS server by default. I know I can add `--dns=...` when running docker commands, but I'd like a way to set the default DNS server for all containers to avoid having to specify the DNS server individually for every container.

How can I set the default DNS server for all containers on Docker for Mac?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In current versions of Docker for Mac, you can go to the Whale Icon -> Preferences -> Daemon -> Advanced and adjust the daemon level DNS settings with a daemon.json config. If your config is currently empty, this would add your own DNS setting with two entries:

```
{
  "dns": ["8.8.8.8", "192.168.0.1"]
}
```

If you already have content in here, then add an entry for "dns" to your json. See the [daemon configuration documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-configuration-file) for other options you can add here.

Comment: For Windows, daemon.json is located at %HOMEPATH%\.docker\daemon.json.  Regardless of environment, if you have simple name resolution, e.g. "machine" resolves to "machine.companyname.local", you'll want to add this line also, to provide a default DNS suffix: `"dns-search": ["companyname.local"]`

Answer (score 2):

As a one liner:

```
sed -i '$s/}/,\n{"dns": ["8.8.8.8", "192.168.0.1"]}}/' ~/.docker/daemon.json
```

(For MacOS, the daemon configuration is in `~/.docker/daemon.json`).